# How to fix "nuxt-error.vue relative module was not found" error in a nuxt/vuetify app?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

**UPDATE:** used @nuxtjs/vuetify module from nuxt-community as a workaround. but will really appreciate if someone can explain this issue.

A nuxt newbee here. I'm having problem to integrate vuetify with my nuxt app scafolded with "npx create-nuxt-app". On running "yarn run dev", terminal shows the following error:

```
 This relative module was not found:
./components/nuxt-error.vue in ./.nuxt/index.js
```

I could've just selected vuetify from nuxt install options. But I want to use vuetify "a la carte" to reduce bundle size. so I'm trying to add it later. no luck so far.

I tried the following steps to add vuetify:

1. create "vuetify.js" file in "plugins" folder.
2. add vuetify to the "plugins" option in nuxt.config.js

Comment: Two things. 1) Your repo gives access denied. 2) Have you tried deleting the .nuxt folder and rebuilding the app?

Comment: @Imre_G  sorry about the link. fixed it. please check now. I'll try deleting nuxt folder now and will let you know the update.

Answer (score 0):

For those stumbling on this question, I had a similar issue. I had installed a new dependency and nuxt was generating the "relative module not found" error.

The solution was to delete the node_modules directory and then run `yarn` so it reinstalled everything.